# Good self-extracting compressor for software content

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, remote-desktop, compression

I often perform upgrades on my client servers via remote desktop. While it's quite powerfull tool, when you want to transfer 100 MB it's a bit of slow. Therefore I use zip to make files smaller and avoid necessity of installing additional software on a client's server.
7zip is a good alternative, but recently I cannot force it to make SFX archives (not implemented - error on 64bit system).

What do you use for compressing software (executables and libraries)?
Is there a better (faster) way to move software from your local PC to servers via RDC?
What are you using on your day-to-day basis?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you 7z if your need a simple click'n'decompress, or NSIS if you need something customizable.

Answer (score 1):

I use [WinRar](http://www.rarlab.com/). For a loss of a few kb (as compared to 7zip) it's far more prevaliant that 7zip, and will create SFX archives at the cost of about 50kb. I use it on x64 workstations and x64 servers without any issues at all.

And of course it stomps all over the built in Windows ZIP utilities.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by "not implemented - error on 64bit system", but 7zip has supported 64bit Windows for a long time. I use it to create sfx archives on several x64 machines. Personally, I would stick with 7zip; it's free, and it gives around about the same compression ratios as Winrar in my experience (sometimes better, sometimes worse - depending on the file type and content). The only thing I've found it to be poor with is JPEGs.

Comment: I'm not sure about the error either - it used to work, but now whenever I try to create SFX from 7zip UI I've got a message box "Not implemented".

Comment: You'll never get compression on JPG's - they're already compressed. That said, apparently 7Zip is faster than WinRAR in almost all applications, however I find that most people can't open a .7z file

Comment: No, I generally don't distribute .7z files; I either use built-in zip or make an sfx.

@karolek - have you updated to the latest version? How about trying an old version?

Answer (score 0):

[winrar](http://www.rarlab.com/) is very fast and supports sfx. Rar also suports many compression formats and is available for a variety of OSs